# Batch For Loop w/ Timestamp

Tags: datetime, for-loop, batch-processing, batch-rename

I need to rename multiple files in a loop and include a time stamp... My struggles begin with updating the timestamp for each file so the file has a unique name.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET date=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
for /f %%a in ('dir /b TCA_*') do (SET
time=%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2,2%  
ren %%a %date%TCA_%time%.txt)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in a loop, variables don't update. To circumnavigate this, the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` script was added.

Basically, if you want them to update, you need to encase them in exclamation marks (!) instead of percent signs (%).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand your recommendation for ! over %.

Unfortunate i still can not seem to make this work.

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    SET date=%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%
    for /f %%a in ('dir /b TCA_*') do 
    (
    SET time=%time:~-11,2%%time:~-8,2%%time:~-5,2%%time:~-2,2%  
    ren %%a %date%TCA_!time!.txt
    )

Comment: @Dave Well, time is a variable, right? So in order for the variable to get updated within the for loop, you must encase it in exclamation marks...

for /f %%a in ('dir /b TCA_*') do (
set time=!time:~-11,2!!time:~-8,2!!time:~-5,2!!time:~2,2! 
ren %%a !date!TCA_!time!.txt
)

Just a side note, I haven't tested this and it is purely an assumption (sorry about that).